# Como validar que no me permita agregar el mismo producto 2 veces

Tags: javascript, ajax

Por favor su apoyo tengo el siguiente problema tengo un modal donde paso los productos a través de un botón a la tabla cotización como muestra la imagen.

No sé cómo validar que no me permita ingresar 2 veces el mismo producto a la tabla que me muestre un mensaje indicando que el producto ya esta agregado.

He intentado de muchas maneras pero no logro resolver el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente me debe permitir ingresar el código 0032773 una sola vez

```js
<script>
 //-- Función agregar productos -- Aqui paso los productos del modal al tabla cotización.
 var artite = 0; var artimp = 0;
 $(document).on("click", ".agrpro", function () {
     row = $(this).closest("tr"); //devuelve el antepasado
     artite = artite + 1;
         artcod = parseInt(row.find("td:eq(0)").text()); 
     var artmod = row.find("td:eq(1)").text();
     var artdes = row.find("td:eq(2)").text();
     var artmar = row.find("td:eq(3)").text();
     var artpsi = row.find("td:eq(4)").text();
     var artpci = row.find("td:eq(5)").text();
     var artsto = row.find("td:eq(8)").text(); //-- Stock
     var artcan = $("#cantAdd_" + artcod).val();        
     var total = parseFloat((artcan * artpsi).toFixed(2));
     var artplb = row.find("td:eq(6)").text();
     var totlib = parseFloat((artcan * artplb).toFixed(2));
     var artpkg = parseFloat(row.find("td:eq(7)").text());
     var totklg = parseFloat((artcan * artpkg).toFixed(2));
     /*var cotimp = (artcan - artsto)*/

     if (artcan > artsto) {
         artimp = cotimp ;
     } else {
         artimp = 0;
     }

     var contbod =
            `<tr class="table-responsive-sm">
             <td class='text-center cotite'>${artite}</td>
             <td class='text-center'>${artcod}</td>
             <td>${artmod}</td>
             <td>${artdes}</td>
             <td>${artmar}</td>
             <td>${artpsi}</td>
             <td>${artpci}</td>
             <td>${artsto}</td>
             <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; color:#660000; font-weight: bold" class="cotcan">${artcan}</td>
             <td>${artimp}</td>
             <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; color:#660000; font-weight: bold" class='subtotal'>${total}</td>
             <td>${artplb}</td>
             <td class="cottlb">${totlib}</td>
             <td>${artpkg}</td>
             <td  class="cottkg">${totklg}</td>
             <td><button type="submit" class="btn_remove btn btn-xs btn-danger ml-1"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>Eliminar</button></td>
             </tr>`;
     $("#tabCot tbody").append(contbod);
/*     document.getElementById("TxtSer").value = final;*/
    /* $('#tabCot').dataTable();*/
     calsum()
     elifil()
 })
 
 //-- Función eliminar productos
 function elifil() {
    $("body").on("click", ".btn_remove", function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        calsum()
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: ok voy ha eliminar los comentarios anteriores.

Comment: Veo que usas `jQuery`. Tienes la opción de "eliminar" la fila de la tabla del modal con `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` al hacer click en el botón correspondiente o inactivar el botón con `$(this).prop('disabled', true);`. Intenta y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Hola DjCrazy, ese boton eliminar es de la tabla donde ya estan pasado los productos despues de dar clic en el boton agregar desde el model.

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema de lógica

Utiliza el id del producto para verificar si ya está en la lista
y así puedes decidir que pasará después.

Si se encuentra puedes aumentar la cantidad o no hacer nada
Si no se encuentra puedes agregarlo.

Comment: Esto es más bien un comentario, y se lo notifique al OP, además que fuimos al [chat] a comentarlo. El confunde los ID reales de los productos, con el orden de la lista (y termina alterando los ID al moverlos de tabla)